# How to use RewriteRule in Apache to redirect from /abc/ to /abc?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

`RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ $1 [R]` redirects from `website.com/abc/` to `website.com/home/user/www/abc`

How do I redirect to the correct location? (`website.com/abc`)

Comment: Your assumption does not appear correct, your rewriterule redirect `anything-without-slash/` to `anything-without-slash`. That means, the redirect to `/home/etc...` must be caused elsewhere

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Abel, but there are no other places I redirect pages, and I've removed all other rewrite rules. I still get redirected to the wrong place.

Comment: Do you any other rule that might conflict with this one? In general you would put those rules that cause an external redirect before those that just cause an internal redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the `RewriteRule` is the matching part, the second the replacement expression. For full-url `RewriteRule`s they should start with a `^/` (slash), because a path after `http://exampl.com` always starts with the root-slash. To redirect `http://example.com/abc/` to `http://example.com/abc` (remove the trailing slash) you can do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+/$ /$1 [R]
```

Comment: A ) was left out so I tried these three:
RewriteRule ^/([^/])+/$ /$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/$ /$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+/)$ /$1 [R]
I'm still redirected to example.com/home/user/www/abc instead of example.com/abc

Comment: other users have commented to use the `L` to finish it (L for Last) and prevent other rewrite rules to pop in. Also, if your page includes a redirect, or there's a redirect in the header of your page, then you can try what you want in Apache but it won't help. Can you provide an example link where this happens?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URL is already being rewritten to a filename and then you are rewriting the filename.  This usually happens when the rewrite rule is being specified in an .htaccess file.  The problem is due to the fact that by the time Apache reads the .htaccess file, it has already resolved all URLs to filenames.  The standard solution to this is to supply a RewriteBase rule in your .htaccess.  Try:

RewriteBase   /

Above your RewriteRule for starters.

More documentation is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#InternalAPI)

Comment: Using only this rule and RewriteEngine on in .htaccess, I still get redirected to website.com/home/user/www/abc. Adding in RewriteBase / gives the same result

Comment: you mention `.htaccess`. Can you adjust `httpd.conf` instead? Are you on a hosting environment where they've simply disallowed this?

Comment: There's no way to do this without RewriteBase?  This site is deployed under several different paths (for testing/development), and I'd like to have the same .htacess work everywhere.  /~user/site/... keeps getting changed to /home/user/site, and of course, that URL doesn't exist!  I don't want to put /~user as the RewriteBase, because it would have to be changed for "user2"

Comment: I suppose you might be able to rewrite based on the full file path, but I have never done that because I would consider it extremely brittle since it depends on the absolute path within the server filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with the additional *L* flag to avoid any further rules to be applied:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ /$1 [R,L]
```

But if nothing else works, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ (/[^/.?\ ]+)/[? ]
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+/$ %1 [R]
```